# Redmine receive mail field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have redmine site:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.3.3.devel
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p448 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.13
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.6.11
  Git                            1.7.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_contacts               3.2.2-light
  redmine_contacts_invoices      2.1.0-light
  redmine_favorite_projects      1.0.0
  redmine_finance                1.0.1-light
  redmine_issue_checklist        2.0.5
  redmine_people                 0.1.6
  redmine_questions              0.0.4
```

I updated ruby and redmine, receiving mail not working (it worked before)

```
/usr/bin/rake -f /var/www/html/redmine/Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_pop3 RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.my.site username=redmine@my.site password=mypassword delete_unprocessed=1 --trace
Your FCGI gem does not contain the FCGI shared library, running pure ruby instead
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_pop3 (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_pop3
rake aborted!
"\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:149:in `encode!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:149:in `fold'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:103:in `wrapped_value'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:69:in `do_encode'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:51:in `encoded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:167:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:206:in `block in encoded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:205:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:205:in `encoded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1801:in `encoded'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:434:in `set_payload_for_mail'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:403:in `block in receive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:401:in `receive'
/var/www/html/redmine/app/models/mail_handler.rb:46:in `receive'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/pop3.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in check'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/pop.rb:665:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/pop.rb:665:in `each_mail'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/pop3.rb:36:in `block in check'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/pop.rb:533:in `start'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/pop3.rb:31:in `check'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:152:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_pop3
```

please help somebody

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when a non-MIME-compliant message was received: the Subject line included a non-ASCII character.

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrade to Redmine 2.6](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade#Step-3-Perform-the-upgrade). That should solve the problem.